# For a nested UITableView inside a UITableViewCell the didSelectRowAt indexPath: is not being called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` nested inside another `UITableView`.
In the nested tableView, when the user taps on a cell, the cell does highlight, but the delegate method `didSelectRowAt indexPath:` is not being called.

Other delegate methods are being called, for example methods like `willDisplay cell: forRowAt indexPath:` or `scrollViewDidScroll(_:)`. So this tells me that the delegates etc. are connected correctly.

In another part of the same application I am using the same kind of structure, `UITableView` inside another `UITableView` and there it works fine.
I compared the two extensively, so far I haven't found the difference, and no clue why one should work and the other not!

Please see the implementation of the nested `UITableViewCell`. 
It would be nice if the console would log the line "touch detected".
It does log the lines "scrolling" and "will display cell".

```
import UIKit

class TestTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

}

extension TestTableViewCell: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FileCell")!
    }
}

extension TestTableViewCell: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("touch detected")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("will display cell")
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        print("scrolling")
    }
}
```

Comment: If you tap and hold for some seconds is it fired ?

Comment: What does the view debugger show though? Because perhaps, in reality, you're tapping on the `UITableViewCell` instead the `UITableViewCell` of your embedded `UITableViewB`

Comment: @Glenn: Do you mean to see if the didSelectRowAt indexPath: of the outer UITableViewCell does get fired?

Comment: @GIJOW No, it's not fired at all..

Comment: Yes, the `didSelectRowAt` delegate method of other `UITableViewCell`. Check the hierarchies of your views as well.

Comment: Once I was working on nested views and google maps and for some reason just the first view on stack could handle the tap. Maybe not connected, but you can try using the gesture delegate to intercept and get some clue `func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {return touch.view == gestureRecognizer.view}` and delegate your class to `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was very simple at last. 
I had a `UITapGestureRecognizer` setup for the outer `UITableView`.
I had this there to dismiss the keyboard on tap.
After removing the `UITapGestureRecognizer` it started working fine.

I completely overlooked this, but it's solved now!